# Problem With Multiple Data Bindings (Silverlight)

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, data-binding, ria, domaindatasource

I am using silverlight to create an Intranet for managing chemical usage. All data is stored in a MS SQL database, and is retrieved by using a DomainService (RIA).

By dragging the database onto the form, Silverlight has created a DomainDataSource based on this table. By then creating a new record using the following code, I am now able to add new records.

```
Me.ChemicalApplicationDomainDataSource.DataView.Add(chemicalApplication)
```

However one of the controls I have on the screen is an AutoCompleteBox. I have bound this to the database, and the values display fine on here. When an item is selected on here, I want to populate the value of a textbox with values retrieved from a second datatable.

I have created an event on the AutoSelectedItemChanged, and added the following code:

```
Context.Load(Context.GetChemicalByNameQuery(AutoMaterialTradeName.Text))
```

I can then bind this to a datagrid.ItemsSource, and it shows the relevent record. But I cannot for the life of me get it to bind to a textbox. Textboxes dont have an ItemsSource, only a DataContext, but binding to this does not seem to display anything..

Any tips on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to bind it to the Text property on the TextBox for that to work. Additionally you would probably need to set the Path property on the binding to get the right property on your object to display.